# Merging the intersection of multiple ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-objects, observablecollection, entity-framework-5

I have multiple ObservableCollections and I want to make an ObservableCollection out of the intersection of all of them. Also, what would be the best way to organize this in MVVM if all the listboxes I'm using to view the individual and merged collections are in 1. the same view and 2. different views.

I'm working in WPF C#.

Thank you! Any link or comment appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `intersection` of two Collections and manually add each object in your collection. This will get you started, simply replace the `'Union'` keyword with `'Intersection'` in the answer - [Intersection of two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565289/union-two-observablecollection-lists)

Comment: Thanks very much, @RV1987. I actually tried that but wasn't able to get it to work. I'll keep trying. Thanks and at least now I know that's the correct approach :)